# In Hadoop, is it possible to balance load between reducers based on the number of records rather than on the number of keys?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, load-balancing

If I understand correctly, `Hadoop` tries to achieve load-balancing between reducers by hashing keys to reducers. This may work well if there is an approximately same number of values associated with each key. In the situation that some keys have much more values than others, how (if at all) is it possible to balance load between reducers based on the number of records rather than on the number of keys?